# How to correctly set virtualhost

Tags: php, xampp

I have a problem with creating a new virtual host on xampp. Here is my snippet

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName origtravel.test
    DocumentRoot "D:\e.batgerel\development\projects\origtravelnew"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "D:\e.batgerel\development\projects\origtravelnew">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost:8080
127.0.0.1   origtravel.test:8080
```

But result is:

[image]

What did i do wrong ? any advice ?

Comment: Are you sure your server is listening on port 8080?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa yes i am sure i configured apache config file 80 to 8080

Comment: Have you restarted apache after you changed the config?

Comment: Yes. But i saw that error log

Comment: Problem detected!
4:17:19 PM  [Tomcat]  Port 8080 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
4:17:19 PM  [Tomcat]  Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:17:19 PM  [Tomcat]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:17:19 PM  [Tomcat]  or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file maps hostnames to ip addresses.

It doesn't map ports to anything. Don't include port numbers in your hostnames.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   origtravel.test
```

Comment: i changed but result is same

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene — Are you sure that the result is really the same (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) and you don't have a *different* error now?

Comment: I am sorry. I need to locate url `origtravel.test:8080`

Comment: That's a hostname with a port number, not a URL. A URL would be something like `http://origtravel.test:8080`

Comment: Yeah. I understand that :)